# get the minimum number of execution for a generator to yield a specific item

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Imagine that we have a generator as simple as the following:

```
def gen_question():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count >= len(letters):
            count = 0
        obj = letters[count]
        yield obj
        count +=1
```

I would like to get the minimum number of times that the generator needs to be executed to yield a specif item. For instance we need to execute it at least 3 times to get the first 'c' item. So 3 is my index of interest in this case. How could I do this in a neat way?

PS : My real function is a keras generator yielding batches of training data and I would like to get the index of a specific batch (i.e. number of extraction to yield a specific batch).

Comment: Take a look at [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a "measuring the system affects the system" kind of scenario. Once you've iterated a generator, the parts you iterated are no longer accessible. You'll need to `itertools.tee` the generator before making the measurement if you want to actually use the generator after (if recreating the same iterator some scratch isn't feasible). Once you've addressed that though, this is as simple as just consuming the iterator and checking what it produced.